# Change menu depending of the view

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, responsive-design

Thank you for stopping by!

I would like to appeal to your wisdom in order to solve a problem that shouln't be that hard :(

I'm developing a website with a big collapsing menu (like a sitemap) that is pretty visual but useless in mobile views, so I created another menu for being showed in mobile and small screen devices.

Summarized code is like:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light ">
            <div class="container-fluid ">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php" id="btnLogo">
                    <img src="../images/logo.png" width="130" height="80" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="logo">
                </a>
                    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right float-right" 
                        type="button" 
                        data-toggle="collapse" 
                        data-target="#desktopMenu" 
                        aria-controls="desktopMenu"  
                        aria-expanded="false">
                        <span>MENU</span>
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>

            <!-- Menu for Desktops -->
            <div id="desktopMenu" class="collapse navbar-collapse">...</div>

            <!-- Menu for small screens -->
            <div id="mobileMenu" class="collapse navbar-collapse">...</div>
```

Question is: Is there any way to change on the fly  "data-target" and "aria-controls" to change between "desktopMenu" and "mobileMenu" depending of the viewport width?

I don't know if this approach is the correct/better one. Please if I'm wrong do not hesitate to suggest another way to do it.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case there is two ways to adapt your page depending on the viewport. One way would be to use `@media-queries` and show/hide one or another element with the `display` attribute.

This will allow you to adjust your code depending on the screen-size.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
// in your case: hide an element, show the other 
#desktopMenu { display:none;} // or display block etc
}
```

You can set up `width` or `height` as you want.

Here is [more about media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

You could also get the current viewport values as so:

```
// Size of browser viewport.
var width = window.innerWidth;
var height = window.innerHeight;
```

And then adjust your code depending on that :

```
if (height >= yourValue) { // or however you want to check the height
document.getElementById('button').setAttribute('data-target', '#desktopMenu'); // or however you want to add/change attributes
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you very much Stacks. It needed some tunning to work in our case but now it's working!